# PostgreSQL Order BY an Array with different types

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I order by an array with such data:

```
{29,635,0,15.7,3414}
{29,635,0,15.7,3415}
{29,635,0,16,3416}
{29,635,0,16,3417}
{29,635,0,16,3418}
{29,635,0,16,3419}
{29,635,0,16,3420}
{29,635,0,16,3421}
{29,635,0,16,3422}
{29,635,0,2.1,100}
{29,635,0,2.1,13}
```

To some point ordering is correct, even with doubles, but after 16 it starts to order from the beggining (2.1). Why is it like that and how can i solve this.
Thanks for anny suggestions!

Comment: what is the query?

Comment: What is the type of that array?

Comment: What is your expected output? For me, this works if the arrays are of type numeric[] https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9b4ceaedbecbe637c0106baf520093e3

Comment: I have a feeling it's sorting by characters, not numbers.  The 1 in 15 and 16 comes before the 2 in 2.1 if it's text.  This is also why 100 is coming before 13.  The first zero in 100 is sorted ahead of the three.

Comment: if it is a numeric array it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a7f3a25eadcd150968da88d17640660c

Comment: Yes, and a text array causes the problem shown above: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0ae3c91edc2c9292d3fdabf0e8e2e8b6

Comment: yes, I cast it to numeric[], but that is the result. The query is simple, select sth from table where id= 1234 order by this_array

Comment: ok, now i see it is ltree, so you are right it is sorted by chars. So, can i cast ltree to int? "::int" and simple cast (ltree as numeric) does not work with ltree.